# Migrate user files to separate shared partition

Tags: partitioning, home-directory, location

I have a set-up a dual boot system with windows 8.1 and Ubuntu. I also created a separate partition for my user files.
I am new to Ubuntu Linux systems and although i have managed to find the 'user-dirs.dirs' file in the '.config' folder, i am not familiar with the location format.

XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"

What does $Home refer to?

What would i enter for another partition?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$HOME is your home-directory, by default `/home/[your username]`.

It is usually available as an environmental-variable. Open a shell and enter `echo $HOME` and you will see it's absolute path.

However, I would not recommend fiddling around there as not all programs use those variables. I'd just create symlinks to the folders in your shared partition, ie:

`ln -s /path/to/your/shared/partition/Downloads $HOME/Downloads`

You will need to delete or rename the actual folder before linking.

Comment: I’m sorry you lost me at 'open a shell', is that the windows equivalent of command prompt? have taken a couple of screen shots in Ubuntu but can't see how to add it to this comment!if you email me directly i can send the pics. Thanks once again for quick response. I am determined to defect to Linux as windows seems to have got progressively worse since windows 95 and have tested win 10 tech preview and that seems the same!

Comment: Found 'terminal' but still not sure what directory path is for the partition, or how to get it.

Comment: Glad to hear you achieved what you wanted. 
In case you sometimes wonder about paths to some partitions you mounted, simply enter "mount" on the terminal, it shows all partitions currtently available to your system.

Comment: links not solid. fell apart so removed ubuntu and re-installed. have now setup a shared ntfs partition and 'hopefully' correctly setup an automatic mount/dismount with etc/fstab. but still need to know differnece between terminal and xterm? Newbie question i know..soz